# Replace non standard characters in php

Tags: php, html, post, str-replace

I'm trying to replace some non standard characters like ë,Ë,ç,Ç with numeric entities like `&#203;` , `&#039;` etc but i ran into a bit of a problem.

When i try to replace them directly like this it works fine:

```
$string = "Ë";
$vname = str_replace("Ë","AAAA",$string);
echo $vname."<br>";
```

an i get AAAA as a result.
But when i try to replace the characters from a string that i get from a form with POST then it doesn't change the characters. Here is an example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$string = $_POST['title'];
if ($string == "Ë")
echo "Yes";
else
echo "No";
$vname = str_replace("Ë","AAAA",$string);
echo $vname."<br>";
echo $string;
}
?>
<form method="post" name="Form">
Title: <input name="title" type="text" value="" size="20"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Any help would be great!!

Comment: What is so "non-standard" about "Ë"?

Comment: what do you get if you echo `$string` after post?

Comment: You probably want to edit your question. Don't forget to preview. When you say "numeric entities like" the next character is capital E with umlaut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your characterset is wrong. I would suggest sending the following header when outputing html:

```
<?php header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Where the charset match the charset you are storing your file in.

Edit: Just some more information. The file you store is in one charset for example latin1, while your browser interprets your html page as another charset (utf-8 for example). When the browser then sends the Ë character, it will send the utf-8 code 0xc38b, while the same character is 0xcb. As you can see, these does not match.

Edit - You can also update the CHARSET via HTML5 or xHTML:

**HTML5**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

**xHTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Thanks man i forgot to set the charset in the admin pages. Changed now and works fine.